# Clicking the login button always leads to this exception, any workaround?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2019

After I click the login button it always shows the error (which you can see in the picture), I do not understand what I'm doing wrong here.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    
            If usertxt.Text = Nothing Or passtxt.Text = Nothing Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Login Details", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Exit Sub
            End If
    
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()
            End If
    
            Using command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User WHERE Username = @Username AND Password = @Password", con)
    
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = usertxt.Text.Trim
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = passtxt.Text.Trim
    
                Dim count = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar())
    
                If count > 0 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Successful")
                    Me.Hide()
    
                    Form1.Show()
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Login Information", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    
                End If
    
            End Using
            con.Close()
    
        End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Check AddWithValue reference. You are using it incorrect. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: I am guessing you are using MS Access as your database. `User` is a [reserved word in MS Access[(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/reserved-words). Wrap the word `User` in square `[]` brackets